# Visual Studio, class/designer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, class

In my Visual Studio Project, some of my classes in the Solution Explorer has
become Designer elements. Instead of the green c#-symbol, they have the little Forms-icon. Anyone know what's happened and how to revert it?

thanks /Sam

Comment: What version of VS? What O/S? What kind of project?

Comment: And do tell us that you he restarted the PC after this happened.

Comment: It's probably winforms and "some classes" are custom controls. Happens to me in past too. You can specifically attribute such classes with `[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategory("Code")]` to avoid this from happening.

Comment: yes, sorry. it is winforms and they’re just some custom controls. @Sinatr, thanks! i’ll try that!